# How can I match the last 4 characters of a word beginning &c using PCRE regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the last four characters (alphanumeric) of all words beginning with the sequence `&c`.

For instance, in the string below, I'd like to match the pieces in bold:

Colour one is &cFF**2AC3** and colour two is &c22**DE4A**.

Can anybody help me with the correct regex expression? I've spent hours on [this great resource](http://regex101.com) to no avail.

Comment: Its all in what comes before `&c`, what comes between `&c` and the last 4 `alnum` and what comes after `alnum`. If you don't care about before the beginning and after the end, and the middle is just non-whitespace, its this `&c\S*\p{Alnum}{4}`. So, you should fill in the blanks which are more important than the known parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like hexadecimal numbers, so use this pattern

```
&c[0-9A-F]{2}\K([0-9A-F]{4})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/44)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/(?:^| )&c\w*(\w{4})\b/
```

If you want to try it in the regex tester you linked to, make sure to use the `g` modifier to see all matches.

Explanation: `(?:^| )` matches either a space or the start of the string, `&c\w*` matches the ampersand and the the first however many characters of the word, and then `\w{4}` captures the last 4 characters.  `\b` on the end asserts a word break (a "non-word" character or the end of the string).

Comment: That almost works except it will capture the last 4 digits of any word beginning with `&`, not specifically `&c`. `/(?:^| )&[c]*([\w]{4})\b/` doesn't match anything...

Comment: I changed to `/(?:^| )&c[\w]*([\w]{4})\b/`, which should work.

Comment: It will match `&c2AC3` which is not what OP wants

Comment: @Smac89 OP wants "all words beginning with the sequence &c".  I think `&c2AC3` is such a word.  If this is not what the OP wants, the question should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
/(?i)\s*&c(?:[a-z0-9]{2})([a-z0-9]{4})\b/
```

append a `g` to the end of it if you want it to find all matches in a given text